# Partial extraction of unstructured data on 2nd instance

Tags: r, regex, edgar

I have a huge text file from Edgar. I want to extract only a portion of text from business risk section.

For example if the text is like :

`Bshehebvegegeveghdhebejejrjbfbfk`

And I want to extract the start position as `he`(2nd instance) end position `ge`(second instance).

So my output will be -
`hebvegege`

I want a code in R. And I am specially interested in the business risk section.

Comment: search for "regular expressions" and you will find examples of how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `gregexpr` to find the index of the starting character for the patterns 'he' and 'ge' and then use `substr` to specify the `start` and `stop` positions of the string to extract the substring

```
i1 <- gregexpr("he", str1)[[1]][2]
i2 <- gregexpr("ge", str1)[[1]][2] +1
substr(str1, i1, i2)
#[1] "hebvegege"
```

---

Or in a single step

```
do.call(substr, c(str1, lapply(c("he", "(?<=g)e"), 
     function(pat) gregexpr(pat, str1, perl=TRUE)[[1]][2]) ))
#[1] "hebvegege"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Bshehebvegegeveghdhebejejrjbfbfk"
```